# How to download a file from owncloud with curl, wget

Tags: curl, wget, owncloud

I installed owncloud on the server!

How I can download shared file with link provided by WebUI from console with wget or curl ?

I tried to download from console with following commands, but this not successfully:

```
wget http://owncloud.example.com/public.php?service=files&t=par7fec5377a27f19654cd0e7623d883
wget http://owncloud.example.com/public.php?service=files&t=par7fec5377a27f19654cd0e7623d883

wget http://owncloud.example.com/public.php?service=files&t=par7fec5377a27f19654cd0e7623d883&download -O file.tar.gz
wget http://owncloud.example.com/public.php?service=files&t=par7fec5377a27f19654cd0e7623d883&download -O file.tar.gz
```

I can download this file from web browser succesfully.

We used Owncloud v. 7.0.4, setuped with chef cookbook [https://github.com/onddo/owncloud-cookbook](https://github.com/owncloud/core)

Comment: What do you mean by "this is not successful"? What kind of errors / not expected behaviour do you get?

Comment: I mean that I cannot download from console with this commands. It's not easy as with dropbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like below worked for me.

```
wget --no-check-certificate "http://owncloud.example.com/public.php?service=files&t=par7fec5377a27f19654cd0e7623d883&download&path=//file.tar.gz"
```

Note double quotes around download link.
URL was "copied download link" from downloads in chrome.

Answer (score 9):

For downloading a list of numbered password protected files use Chrome developer "Copy as cURL" feature (http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2013/chrome-feature-copy-as-curl) to get a cURL command with cookie, then copy paste first file name to write a download script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for number in $(seq -w 37)
do
    curl -o "file.part0$number.zip" "<URL of first file including $number>" \
       -H parameters from "Copy as cURL"
done
```

Comment: Thanks mostly for the link to that post - I didn't really use your script :-)

Comment: The "copy as cURL" worked for me, too, to download a password protected file :)

Comment: Wasn't aware of this awesome function. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

## use wget to download from public link owncloud

```
$wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition "https://owncloud/link"
```

- --content-disposition (get the name from the content-disposition header from the requests, name of the file from the url)
- --no-check-certificate (skip certificate error)
- -O file.name (to specify new name)

## curl

```
$curl -J -O "https://link/path"
```

- -J (use remote header name)
- -O (use remote name)

Comment: For me the `curl -J -O "https://example.com/s/<FUNNY_KEY_VALUE>/download"` variety worked. Copied the link by right-clicking the `Download` button at the right hand side of the top frame, effectively downloading the content of a full shared directory structure. Instead, you can also get the download link of individual files, by right-clicking the file name. I have not found a way to get such a link for only one directory within the folder structure.

Comment: I have now found a way to download only a particular folder (but all files within that folder): you can take the link of any of the contained files and just delete everything starting from the `&files=` onwards.